# Basic Probability Question: What is the probability that my data point belong to a given distribution?

Tags: probability

I have a distribution, D and a data point, X. Assuming that the distribution is Normal with parameters mu and sigma, what is the probability that X belongs to D?

I tried looking for the answer online but I couldn't find any. I looked up different questions including [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145294/how-likely-is-it-that-a-value-belongs-to-a-given-distribution) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195166/how-to-calculate-the-probability-that-a-scalar-data-point-maps-to-a-class) but couldn't find my answer.

Edit 1: I am looking at soft assignments in probabilistic clustering (i.e. mixture models) and N is one of the clusters. Computing that probability that a point X belongs to a cluster N is determined by the prior probability and N(x | mu, sigma). My question is how to calculate N(x| mu, sigma).

Comment: So far, you haven't described any mechanism whereby a probability can be attached to the statement "X belongs to D."  Since D is Normal, literally *any* number can arise from it (and all numbers have exactly the same probability of arising: namely, zero).  So what are you trying to determine and how is X produced? (I see your question is *exactly* the same as one you reference and that we're about to go down exactly the same path as the comment thread to that one, so please study it first.)

Comment: I did go through the question but I couldn't find a suitable answer. I have added more context to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Re the edit: you can find formulas for the Normal density in thousands of posts on this site.  A search will turn up a few of them: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=formula+normal+distribution+density.  Is that what you're asking about?  If not, then could you clarify what you mean by "calculate $N(x\mid\mu,\sigma)$"?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know which formulas you are talking about. I think that's the answer I am looking for. A resource pointing to such formulas perhaps.

Comment: Google "normal distribution" (or replace "Normal" by any other distribution name), and link to the Wikipedia entry. On the upper right of the first page you will find a summary that includes the formulas.